# Android - Firebase getting all the data that is on another table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In practice, people can send requests to each other. What I want to do is to show all the requests sent to one person in that person's profile. I can show all users information with firebase adapter in recyclerview but I could not show only request senders. How can I do? I'd be very happy if you could give an idea to us.

[image: Firebase structure]

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to show the children names of the parent you can use this code.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req").child("recieved").child("id_of_reciepent");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String request_sender_id = (String) ds.getKey();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the names only of the friends who sent a friend request, you need to query your database twice. Please use the following code in order to achieve this.

```
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Friend_req").child("recieved").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("Users").child();
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener(key) {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = dSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
Bob
Second Friend
```